# How do I see my own questions/answers that I deleted?

Tags: support, questions, answers, deleted-questions

I deleted a question today which I want to undelete. However, I don't remember the question ID and my browser history was recently cleared, so I am not sure how else I can find it.

How do I go about viewing my questions/answers that I've deleted? Is there a way to find this within my profile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This *may* be a 10k+ user ability but give it a try...

1. Go to your user profile for WPSE.
2. Click on the "Activity" tab
3. Below your reputation chart is a list of tabs, click "questions"
4. At the veryyyy bottom left is a link "deleted recent question" - click it

If there doesn't work there's an "all actions" tab in the Activity profile which may shed some light. I could also link you to the question if need be.

As OP points out in the comments below you may also follow this link and replace `{ID}` with your profiles user ID:

```
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-q‌​uestions/{ID}
```

Comment: Found it, excellent. Not sure why it's discreetly placed there. It could easily be placed on top next to "_views_" when sorting through your own questions. I find myself having trouble navigating to particular pages like this in Stack Exchanges overall. Tooks me till now to find the link to our WPSE chat page... Here's the URL format for future reference `https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/ID` May you add that to your answer for the record?